# Power regression line for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, excel, highcharts

I'm currently about to implement the following trendline plugin from Highcharts:

```
http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry?search=trendline
Highcharts regression
Date: 2014-05-23
This allows you to add regression lines to any series. 
Supports: linear, polynomial, logarithmic, exponential and loess. Calculates the r-value.
```

Does anyone know if there's a way to add in a Power regression line? It seems like this is perhaps the most common of the (polynomial, logarithmic, exponential, power) grouping when I'm in excel.

How could I add this in?

Comment: Looking into this plugin code I think it is possible to add new function inside it. I am seeing even already defined _power function in this plugin. The best option will be to write on this plugin github with question about it. Here you can find link to github:
https://github.com/streamlinesocial/highcharts-regression/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue

Comment: @david542: Did you manage to find a power regression line plugin?